# Построение БД - структура и отношения

Tags: база-данных, структуры

Доброго времени суток.
У меня есть задача - сделать БД по описанию:
*Есть аукционы с лотами.

У аукциона есть номер, дата и время начала и окончания.

У каждого аукциона внутри есть тематические категории.

 Лоты разбиты по этим тематическим категориям.

 Один лот может находиться в нескольких категориях.

 У каждого лота собственная дата и время окончания торгов, есть название, описание, несколько изображений(любое количество), минимальная цена выкупа

Пользователи делают ставки у конкретных лотов, выигрывает тот, кто поставил максимальную ставку до окончания торгов по лоту.*

Не понимаю как построить структуру и отношения в этой бд, пробовал и так:
**Auction :** id , #,Data , timeStart , timeEnd
**category:** id , name
**lots:** id , name , DataEnd , timeEnd, img , description , auction_id , category_id
**rates:** id , lot_id , amount

но тут, не хватает чего-то... решил добавить ещё такой вариант:

**Auction:** id, #, time.start, time.end, category_id
**Category:** id, name
**Lots:** id, name, data.end, time.end, min.rate,description,img_id,lot-cat_id
**Lot-Category:** id, lot_id, category_id
**rate:** id, lot_id, auction_id, rate
**img:** id, name, lot_id

В итоге совсем запутался... может кто помочь с этим?
Я даже не то, что прошу решения, сколько подсказки как это сделать, не работал с БД почти до этого в таком плане.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Auction**: id, date , startTime, endTime

**Category**: id, name

**Lot**: id, name, endTime, minRate, description (Тут категория и картинка не нужна, так как если будем плодить такую запись под каждую картинку или категорию привязанную к лоту, то будет повтор всей остальной информации)

**CategoryToLot**: id, lotId, catId

**ImgToLot**: id, imgId, lotId

**images**: id, path, type(На случай если картинки будут подвязываться в дальнейшем и к другим сущностям), name

**AuctionLots**: id, auctionId, lotId

Можешь обьяснить, rates это что? ставки?
Названия сам подберешь. Почитай [на счет связей тут](https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/sql-for-beginners-part-3-database-relationships--net-8561)